# In Spring Tool Suite how can I create another scheme for my own key bindings

Tags: eclipse, ide, customization, spring-tool-suite

I often like to bind my own keys for tasks I do often however if I leave it in default I find it is lost after a short while.  How can I create my own scheme?  I see that 'default' already exists along with 'Emacs'.  How can I add my own?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a way to create your own scheme via the UI. You might be able to write a custom plugin for Eclipse/STS that does this, but that is a totally different story.

Answer (score -1):

You must go to Window > Preferences > General > Keys
And there you can create your own shortcuts or modify existing ones.

Comment: I know how to map my own keys.  The question is how do I save them under my own scheme.